# Drupal 7 module custom JavaScript AJAX function calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal-7

I'm trying to add some JavaScript functionality to a collection of checkboxes in a node edit form as illustrated below:

[image]

When each box is checked/unchecked, I want my AJAX code to respond. My attempt to attach some AJAX functionality to the checkboxes seem to work as the image shows but there are two problems:

1. I get the following error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined --- ajax.js**
2. If I uncheck the same box and re-checked, my AJAX code does not respond (I concede that could be because of the above error)

The code below is my module code where I'm adding the sponsors.js code is loaded:

```
function content_event_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

    if($form_id == 'SPECIFIC-FORM-ID'){

        drupal_add_js( drupal_get_path('module', 'content_event') . '/js/sponsors.js', array('type'=>'file', 'scope'=>'header', 'group'=>'JS_THEME') );

        drupal_add_js(array('content_event' => $form['field_exhibitor'][$form['field_sponsors']['#language']]['#default_value']), 'setting');

        /******************************/
        $form['field_exhibitor'][$form['#node']->language]['#ajax'] = array(
          'callback' => 'my_js',
        );

    }
}

function my_js(){
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('fieldset#node_event_major__form_group_sponsors div.form-type-checkbox', 'test');// . $element['country']['#id'], 'focus');
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

The **my_js** function is my ajax call-back function from which I'm attempting to call the **test** function in my js code.

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.contentevent = {
        attach: function (context) {

            //DEFAULT - hide all sponsor checkboxes
            $('fieldset#node_event_major__form_group_sponsors div.form-type-checkbox').hide();

            $items = Drupal.settings['content_event'];
            $($items).each( 
                function($item){
                    Drupal.behaviors.showSponsor($item);
                }
            ); //end each

            Drupal.behaviors.test = function() {
                console.log('Testing ... Testing!!!');
            };

        }
    };

    Drupal.behaviors.showSponsor = function($index) {
        console.log('Test function responding: ' + $index);
        $('fieldset#node_event_major__form_group_sponsors div.form-type-checkbox input[value=' + Drupal.settings['content_event'][$index] +']').parent().show();
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the `ajax_command_invoke` function which results in this:
**`$('fieldset#node_event_major__form_group_sponsors div.form-type-checkbox').test();`**

Your **`test`** function must be outside the "Drupal.behaviors" scope or try to change the second parameter to **`ajax_command_invoke`** to "Drupal.behaviors.test" if you want to continue this way (didn't tested).

I suggest choosing the first method.